# Composer cannot find package for a Symfony2 bundle

Tags: github, bundle, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm creating a **Symfony2** bundle hosted on *GitHub*. I suppose that everything is configured well! However, when I try to install it something goes wrong.

Here follows a summary of the key info.

First, in my Symfony2 app I update the `composer.json` as follows:

```
"require": {
     ...,
    "bundle-name": "dev-master"
},
```

When I try to install the bundle through the command `php composer.phar update`, I get the following error:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package bundle-name could 
      not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according 
   to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> 
   for more details.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you added repository for "robertotru/to-inline-style-email-bundle" , i could'nt find it on [packagist](http://packagist.org)

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault Ops! No, I missed that step! Can you please provide a link to a tutorial that explains that?

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault Hey I did it! Now it works! Please, post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add repository for "bundle-name". 
I couldn't find it on [packagist](http://packagist.org), so register it first.